# Can user group permissions be used to override entry section locale settings?

Tags: users, localization, sections, user-groups, multi-site

I have created a localized site with 9 locales for a client in craft v2.6. They are now requesting us to create a user group for each locale so they can assign editors for each of those regions. When a user creates a new entry they want the new entry to be enabled only for the preferred locale for that user instead of the default enabled locales that are set in the section setting. Is it possible to override a section’s settings based on user group permissions? I know this is a strange request and I don't believe it is doable but wanted to see if anyone had any thoughts on this.

Comment: This is totally possible but you have to dig deep into Craft and Yii and it requires many changes/hacks into the core to achieve this without breaking updates. We are doing this for various projects by overwriting classes and certain functions to district which elements the user is able to see/edit/write. I think the much easier method is what Brad explained to reject the saving process

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to override a section’s settings based on user group permissions?

There's nothing native in Craft that would allow you to do this.

Maybe you could do something like write a plugin that listened to the [onBeforeSaveEntry](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onBeforeSaveEntry) event and simulate it by enabling/disabling it for various locales based on the current user's permissions.